# Flex direction column with 100% height dont work with overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have page with 100% height and column with items+form, items alighn to buttom. Then i add new items overflow scroll dont work.

```
 <div class="column">
          <div class="items">
            <div class="item">Harry Potter</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form"><button>ADD items</button></div>
  </div>

body,html{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.column{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #766;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.items{
  background-color: #432;
  padding: 8px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.item {
   margin: 4px;
   background-color: orange;
}

.form{
  background-color: #834;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

You can try in [sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/k2uemLdv/) (for correct hide jsfiddle console):

[image]

Comment: instead of flex-end, use margin-top auto on the element

Comment: i need flex-end , need items align to buttom

Comment: margin-top:auto will give you the same alignment to the bottom + will fix your overflow issue

Comment: dont work with  "instead of flex-end, use margin-top auto".  Items alight to top, i need buttom https://i.ibb.co/yRjFwwR/list.png

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/acyznvk6/

Comment: oh margin-auto only to first child. Yes its work thx :)  What is hack ? why with flex-end dont work?

Comment: this is not a hack, margin are a feature to align item in Flexbox and check the duplicate to understand why flex-end is not good here